New double wall oven install on one 12 awg. With both ovens on, will that blow 20 amp breaker?
New double wall oven draws 4.0 kW each with pigtail out of each. Installation instructions say to connect one 12 awg line in to both pigtails. If both ovens are on will that not trip the 20 amp breaker that is required for 12 awg?
Whirlpool model WOD52ES4MZ. enter image description here


Make/model of your oven and pictures of your installation instructions would really help identify what's going on and what advice to give.

Can you clarify "4.0kW each" and "pigtail out of each"?

8 kW at 240 VAC draws ~33 amps.

Unless it is chinese junk, it should be UL listed and those instructions should be right.  It is 240v, so two hots on a double 20 amp breaker.

You need to install appliances which are UL Listed per NEC 110.2. (alternate: CSA or ETL listed. In the North American marketplace, CE or CCC are pretty much always fake marks, indicating danger.)
You need to follow labeling, instructions per NEC 110.3(B). And if they are silent on the question, look at NEC 220.55.
Under 220.55, two 4kW ovens doesn't seem terribly far off, since they get a 65% demand factor so 5200 watts, and the limit on a 20A circuit is 4800 watts.  It's possible UL did the necessary testing to say "Good enough!"
Now, with UL approved combinations, it is absolutely possible to trip the breaker by using them in a "fake" way which is designed to taunt the breaker.  Such as, throwing every burner and oven to max within seconds of each other, something a normal chef would be unlikely to do in the course of legitimate cooking.
For a deep dive into how burners are controlled, see this excellent Technology Connections video. Ovens are more directly thermostatic, but same idea - once they reach operating temp, they start clicking on/off.  A breaker will tend to tolerate this, as they have an inverse-time trip mode (the bigger the overload the less time they allow).

This answer is correct but I do not understand the reasoning behind demand-factoring multiple cooking appliances.  Note these are ovens, not ranges.  If you have lots of ovens it is precisely because you use them all at once, and in the case ovens it is perfectly normal to preheat them all at once, at the beginning of the day or of prepping a meal.  During use they'll cycle diversely but preheating is full power for 5 to 60 minutes.   I accept (and upvoted) this but do not understand the background.

@jay613 -- a low overload for a few minutes won't be enough to cause trouble (see your nearest friendly breaker trip curve for details).

1.7X breaker rating for 20 minutes? IDK.   Maybe what is fishy here is one oven with two connections to one circuit.  The docs might help understand this.

Referring to the added documentation, the warning box with the zappy hand is a misprint.  Use the table on the last page and instructions after it.  Sounds like you're in the last row, you need a 40A circuit.

TL;DR Wire the two ovens together in a junction box and feed it with a 40A circuit with 8 AWG or larger wire.
Can't read much from the fuzzy images of pages. But with the model # WOD52ES4MZ I can go to the full PDF Installation Manual and looking at the pictures on the Home Depot and Whirlpool web sites, it all makes sense:

Two Ovens in One vs. Two Ovens "Together"

A typical "double oven" is two "baking chambers" with one control panel. This model is actually two full ovens, each with its own control panel, but designed, sold and installed as one large unit. That has certain advantages (eliminates many single points of failure - e.g., a control panel failure or thermal fuse on one oven will have absolutely no effect on the other oven) and certain disadvantages (two control panels means a higher manufacturing cost, which presumably affects the retail price in some way). But that does explain why there are indeed two separate power whips - one going to each control panel, and each control panel in turn controls power to one oven chamber.

Wiring

Page 9 of the manual (one of the fuzzy images) does indeed show connecting the hot wires and neutral wires of the two oven power supplies together to the same circuit.

Power Requirements/Circuit Size

Page 7 says this model is 6.3 kW @ 208V or 8.4 kW @ 240 V. Those numbers are exactly double the single-oven numbers, which makes sense in this design.
On the same page it says:

Dual oven installations with the combined models rated 6.3 kW and above at 208/240 V require a separate 40 A circuit.

which also makes perfect sense. Single oven = 20A circuit. Double oven = 40A circuit. With a double oven, the only 12 AWG wire you are using is the wire supplied by the manufacturer in the wire whip, and that is approved by UL or ETL, and is in fact appropriate because each 1/2 of the double oven really only needs 20A.
But the wire you connect to the double oven (to the two whips together in one junction box) must be rated for 40A. Which means that you need a 40A breaker and a minimum size wire of 8 AWG.
So that leaves open the question of why page 8 says:

Use 12 gauge copper wire.

and the answer is inertia.
As of today (May 30, 2024), the copy of the installation manual on the Home Depot web site does not even include the box that shows different model power requirements and does not include the 40A circuit requirement for double ovens. The link I included is from the Whirlpool web site and it does (currently) include that information.
My theory is that Whirlpool originally made a manual for the single oven. Then they came up with the double oven as an alternative. Since each of the ovens in the double oven has its own control panel and wiring, very little needed to be changed except for some mechanical pieces added to hold the two ovens together as a unit. Then they had to revise the manual to include all the relevant information for the double oven models. On the first round (manual ID W11508921A, dated 11/21 - see Home Depot) they missed the electrical changes except that they included the physical wiring diagram (junction box showing two whips). On the fourth round (W11508921D, dated 04/23 - see Whirlpool) they added model-specific information and the related circuit sizes, but still didn't correct the 12 AWG text.
If they ever make W11508921E then there is a good chance they'll fix the "12 AWG" line.

Downvoter care to explain what is wrong with my answer?
